# Postscreen sometimes stops the mail with 450 4.3.2 Service currently unavailable

Tags: postfix, spam, postscreen

I have a problem with postfix *sometimes*, inconsistently rejecting client mails:

```
Sep 15 09:24:07 mail postfix/postscreen[16209]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from [x.x.x.x]:15037: 450 4.3.2 Service currently unavailable; from=<user@externaldomain.com>, to=<user@ourdomain.com>, proto=ESMTP, helo=<mail.external.com>
Sep 16 07:41:01 mail postfix/postscreen[16209]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from [x.x.x.x]:13720: 450 4.3.2 Service currently unavailable; from=<user@externaldomain.com>, to=<user@ourdomain.com>, proto=ESMTP, helo=<mail.external.com>
Sep 16 09:08:22 mail postfix/postscreen[16209]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from [x.x.x.x]:34719: 450 4.3.2 Service currently unavailable; from=<user@externaldomain.com>, to=<user@ourdomain.com>, proto=ESMTP, helo=<mail.external.com>
```

This is a debian wheezy server running postfix 2.9.6-2.  Looking at the performance graphs at the given time, neither the server, nor postfix had high load, so I doubt it rejected for that.

Is there a way to reduce the load on this *postscreen* daemon, disable it or whitelist specific users so they can "pass through it"?

Answer (score 10):

Those error was appeared in your log because you have enabled **deep protocol tests** as documented in [POSTSCREEN_README](http://www.postfix.org/POSTSCREEN_README.html#after_220). Because postscreen [isn't proxy](http://www.postfix.org/POSTSCREEN_README.html#after_220), then it will become sort of [greylisting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greylisting) when you defer client connection in first attempt. More info in these two mailing list thread, [this one](http://postfix.1071664.n5.nabble.com/postscreen-service-not-available-rejection-msg-td39897.html) and [this one](http://postfix.1071664.n5.nabble.com/Postscreen-config-td57410.html).

- If you don't know/understand what happened in **deep protocol tests**, don't enable it. Disable it via change these parameter in `main.cf`

  ```
  postscreen_bare_newline_enable = no
  postscreen_non_smtp_command_enable = no
  postscreen_pipelining_enable = no
  ```
- If you want to enable it while whitelisting some client, take a look of parameter [postscreen_access_list](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#postscreen_access_list) in this [page](http://www.postfix.org/POSTSCREEN_README.html#perm_white_black). In short, add parameter `postscreen_access_list`  in `main.cf`

  ```
  postscreen_access_list = cidr:/etc/postfix/postscreen_access.cidr
  ```

  Then in `/etc/postfix/postscreen_access.cidr`, define the acl

  ```
  # Rules are evaluated in the order as specified.
  # Blacklist 192.168.* except 192.168.0.1.
  192.168.0.1          permit
  192.168.0.0/16       reject
  ```